# Add class "active" to span with JQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have three spans

```
$(".regions_list li span")
[
<span>​text0</span>​
, 
<span>text1​</span>​
, 
<span>​text2</span>​
]
```

I want to add active class for span that text equal with `myVariable`

```
  myVariable = "text2";
  $(".regions_list li span").eq(myVariable).addClass("active");
```

but this method doens't work for this example.

some proposal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using jQuery, use the [`contains`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector to select all elements that contain the specified text:

```
var myVariable = "text2";
$(".regions_list li span:contains(" + myVariable + ")").addClass("active");
```

**Notice:** You have no guarantee with this solution that only *"text2"* spans elements would be selected because `contains` functioning pretty much like the SQL `like` clause, it will select whatever starts or ends with the given text. You may enforce exact-match comparison on it as [@xec suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23222719/952310):

```
$(".regions_list li span").filter(function(){
    return $(this).text() === myVariable;
}).addClass("active");
```

Look at my jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/ynevet/337NV/

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`:contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

```
$(".regions_list li span:contains('"+myVariable+"')").addClass("active");
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/baJLx/)

Comment: This solution is fine as long as you never have any false positives ('contains' http://jsfiddle.net/baJLx/3/ vs 'is' http://jsfiddle.net/baJLx/4/)

Answer (score 2):

Although `contains` work, I personally think, you can do this (*See bottom for why*):

```
$(".regions_list li span").filter(function(){
   return $(this).text() == myVariable;
}).addClass("active");
```

Take a look at [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/so-filter-vs-contains). This method is the fastest and most efficient.

`contains` is slow when compared to `filter`.

Comment: Hehe, this is exactly the same code as my answer, except you're arguing the performance angle instead of the precision :) +1 to you dear sir

Comment: @xec Well, don't call me sir. I'm only 14 ;)

Comment: your jsperf is a little flawed, you left out the other option for using `:contains` http://jsperf.com/so-filter-vs-contains/2 which makes them relatively equivalent in terms of speed. I'd still prefer your method though if i wanted to ensure an exact match.

Comment: The reason using `:contains` in a filter is faster than using it in the original selector is when you use it in the original selector, jquery can no longer use `document.querySelectorAll` to make the selection due to the custom `:contains` selector. By spitting it into two actions, jquery can use the more efficient `document.querySelectorAll()` then do the filter on the result.

Comment: @KevinB, shall I include it in my answer?

Comment: If you wish, it's common knowledge, not something I came up with on my own.

Comment: The inner workings of jQuery isn't exactly common knowledge, this is good to know. Also, doing `this.innerHTML === myVariable` is quicker yet. On the other hand it's also premature optimization ;)

Comment: well, it's in the api documentation, :) http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/jquery-selector-extensions/

Comment: Amit, i would roll back the answer if i was you. In the jsperf link, it appears the original `.filter()` is still the quickest, and using `:contains()` could cause false positives (see my answer)

Comment: yeah your original solution was fine, i would have just added to it. now it's confusing.

Comment: @xec, In my system, Kevin's answer cam first ;) However I rolled back my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Like some other answers suggest, using `:contains()` can work, as long as it doesn't need to be an exact match. `:contains(text2)` will match `<span>text2</span>` as well as potentially false positives, such as  `<span>text23</span>`.

If you need an exact match, you could use a custom filter instead;

```
$(".regions_list li span").filter(function(){
    return $(this).text() === myVariable;
}).addClass("active");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/baJLx/4/

Comment: Did you try what you assume with "text23"?

Answer (score 0):

Use [contains](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector of jquery for that

```
$("span:contains('"+myVariable+"')").addClass("active");
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try below code:

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/baJLx/2/)**

```
var myVariable = "text1";
$(".regions_list li span:contains("+myVariable+")").addClass("active");
```